# I have upgraded my raspiblitz v 1.7.2 directly to v 1.10. After restart and "upgrade" it shows "sparco-host=0.0.0.0: unknown option" in logs

Tags: core-lightning, raspberry-pi

I was lazy and have upgraded my raspiblitz v 1.7.2 directly to v 1.10 instead of going through 1.8, 1.9.

After restart and selecting "upgrade" it continuously shows "Lightning : prepare resync" in console menu and "sparco-host=0.0.0.0: unknown option" in logs.

```
lightning: Config file /home/bitcoin/.lightning/config line 15: sparco-host=0.0.0.0: unknown option
```

When I inspecting the lightningd.service status, it failed to start and restart continuously.
It also shows, that it cannot find module gunicorn.

What can I do to fix that issue?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research and trying to install `gunicorn` in lightningd virtual environment and some other trials i just examined the `/home/bitcoin/.lightning/config` file, stopped `lightningd.service`, commented out the lines starting with "sparco" and started the lightningd.service again.

It doesn't show the error regarding this property anymore, starts checking the DB, found and fixed a couple of problems and now it runs fine.

I guess this properties are from older versions and perhaps are not used in the newer core-lightning anymore.

If anybody know, if lightning needs these `sparco-*` please leave the comment below.